# EventProcessorClient delays between events

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to create a way to handle spikes of events in the eventhub. My current poc solution is just to fire and forget tasks as I'm consuming events, instead of awaiting them and then throttle parallel task amount using semaphore to avoid resource starvation.

Utility that throttles things:

```
    public class ThrottledParallelTaskFactory
    {
        ...

        public Task StartNew(Func<Task> func)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Available semaphore count {AvailableDataConsumerCount} out of total {DataConsumerCountLimit}",  _semaphore.CurrentCount, _limit);
            _semaphoreSlim.Wait(_timeout);  
            
            _ = Task.Run(func)
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.Status is TaskStatus.Faulted or TaskStatus.Canceled or TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                    {
                        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
                        _logger.LogDebug("Available semaphore count {AvailableDataConsumerCount} out of total {DataConsumerCountLimit}", _semaphore.CurrentCount, _limit);
                    }
                    if (t.Status is TaskStatus.Canceled or TaskStatus.Faulted)
                    {
                        _logger?.LogError(t.Exception, "Parallel task failed");
                    }
                });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

My `EventProcessorClient.ProcessEventAsync` delegate:

```
 private Task ProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs arg)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                _throttledParallelTaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to process event");
            }
            _logger.LogDebug($"Took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

After running this setup for a while, I noticed that my throttler's Semaphore maxes out at 2-3 tasks running in parallel, when my configured limit is 15. This kind of suggests to me that my handler takes 333-500ms to finish, but Stopwatch inside the handler says that the whole handler takes 0 ms to execute. I later added timestamp logging of when handler starts/ends to confirm it and it does take 0-1ms, but there's a mystery 300-600ms gap between them. **NOTE: For current tests, this client is processing a backlog of millions of events, it's not processing live data, which could cause similar delays between events.**

Does by any chance `EventProcessorClient` checkpoint internally after every single event? 300-500ms seems massive in my head.
I have both used default cached event/prefetch counts and increased ones without much difference.

**Edit:**

It ended up being not implementation related networking issue

Comment: The processor itself has a high degree of concurrency, as each owned partition is encapsulated in a dedicated background task, as is the management of the processor.  Each of those is a highly asynchronous workflow.  The most likely reason that you're seeing delays is contention in the thread pool, causing continuations and new tasks to be slow to be scheduled.   As a general rule, we'd advise testing with no more than a 1:1 relationship between partitions owned and the number of processors in the system when you're doing concurrent work to process events.

Comment: From the point of EventHub - currently there's just a single partition due to some internal decisions, so technically there's just 1 partition and 1 processor. Also, key detail I forgot to mention that this was happening only when deployed to k8s cluster and not locally. But as in my edit - found the issue which happened to be not related to implementation at all

Answer (score 2):

You are not measuring the right thing and basically you are using async/await & Task wrong.

```cs
        private Task ProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs arg)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                _throttledParallelTaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to process event");
            }
            _logger.LogDebug($"Took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

In the above code the call to `_throttledParallelTaskFactory.StartNew` is not awaited. So the stopwatch has nothing to measure. Furthermore, since the call is not awaited any exception won't be caught.

You should move the exception handling and time measurement to the `StartNew` method like this:

```cs
        private Task ProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs arg)
        {
            _throttledParallelTaskFactory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(1000));
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

```cs
public class ThrottledParallelTaskFactory
{
    public async Task StartNew(Func<Task> func)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _logger.LogDebug("Available semaphore count {AvailableDataConsumerCount} out of total {DataConsumerCountLimit}", _semaphore.CurrentCount, _limit);
        _semaphoreSlim.Wait(_timeout);
        
        try
        {
            await func.Invoke();
        }
        catch
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to process event");
            _logger?.LogError(t.Exception, "Parallel task failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
            _logger.LogDebug("Available semaphore count {AvailableDataConsumerCount} out of total {DataConsumerCountLimit}", _semaphore.CurrentCount, _limit);
            _logger.LogDebug($"Took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }
    }
}
```

See how we got rid of the call to `ContinueWith`? Also, since the func already represents a `Task` there is no need to wrap the code in a call to `Task.Run`.

> Does by any chance EventProcessorClient checkpoint internally after every single event?

No, it does not. You have to do checkpointing manually.

Comment: You're right about task stuff, I got into bad habit of just putting small blocks of code from different sources ending up with this Frankenstein's monster. (Stopwatch was just to quickly check if there's no 'magic' happening that takes up those mysterious 300 ms).

Result however with your changes is still the same - there are 300-600ms gaps between event handler calls.

Comment: I guess my option could be switch to `EventHubConsumerClient` since I haven't had issues with parallelizing it and do checkpointing myself instead

Comment: @Edgar.A:  Can you clarify the approach that you're considering for the `EventHubConsumerClient`?

Comment: Sorry, it was more of an shower thought, and shouldn't be taken seriously